# Random Independent set in 3-uniform hypergraph

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

What is the maximum size of an [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) set in a [3-uniform hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) if we choose it randomly from the set of vertices of the hypergraph?
Is there any reference/idea to this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on your hypergraph? For graphs, there's the [well-known result by Ajtai, Komlós, and Szemerédi](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(80)90030-8) which considers the size of a uniformly random independent set of a *triangle-free* graph. The same idea would probably work for 3-uniform hypergraphs if you had some assumptions about what the neighborhood of a vertex looked like.

Comment: (Here, "well-known" = "I would expect to see it in a graduate-level class on probabilistic combinatorics", so don't feel bad if you haven't seen it.)